# Parse unique values from CSV

Tags: ruby, csv, parsing

I have `file.csv`:

```
user,name
1,Jim
1,Jim
2,Michael
3,Scott
4,Dwight
4,Dwight
5,Pam
```

I just want one of the unique entries from the file and then import it. I desire:

```
user,name
1,Jim
2,Michael
3,Scott
4,Dwight
5,Pam
```

I can parse through the CSV and import it to my database.

```
CSV.foreach("file.csv", :headers => true).each do |row|
  # do stuff to ignore dupes

  # doing stuff to import to db
end
```

I assume I need to keep track of the id's as I parse through, but I am not sure what the next step would be.

Comment: For your example, please show the Ruby object you "desire" to construct (a string?, an array?, a hash? a CSV file?). Is the header relevant? What is to be unique? The numbers? The lines? Could the file contain "5,Pam" on one line and "5,Lucy" on another?

Comment: @CarySwoveland id's will always belong to the same name fortunately

Comment: Thank you, but that answers just one of several questions I asked. When clarifying a question it's best to edit the question rather than elaborate in comments, as not all readers read all the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out given my issue. Maybe not best practice but this seems to work for what I needed.

```
previous_user = nil

CSV.foreach("file.csv", :headers => true).each do |row|
  # do stuff to ignore dupes
  current_user = row['user']

  next if current_user == previous_user

  # doing stuff to import to db
  previous_user = current_user
end
```

Answer (score 1):

can try:

```
CSV.read("file.csv", :headers => true).uniq(&:last).each do |row|
   print row
end
```

**output:**

```
1,Jim
2,Michael
3,Scott
4,Dwight
5,Pam
```

Comment: It feels to me like the ids and the names match. Therefore `uniq` without an argument should be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

When I see this kind of task, I always wonder why for God’s sake one needs to abuse CSV here?

```
input = 'user,name
1,Jim
1,Jim
2,Michael
3,Scott
4,Dwight
4,Dwight
5,Pam'
#⇒ "user,name\n1,Jim\n1,Jim\n2,Michael\n3,Scott\n4,Dwight\n4,Dwight\n5,Pam"
input.split[1..-1].map { |line| line.split(',').last }.uniq
#⇒ ["Jim", "Michael", "Scott", "Dwight", "Pam"]
```

or, with indices:

```
input.split[1..-1].uniq
#⇒ ["1,Jim", "2,Michael", "3,Scott", "4,Dwight", "5,Pam"]
```

Comment: If it is **really** CSV, an entry could look like `126,"Arthur Dent"` or `127,"Prefect, Ford"`, in which case splitting would not yield the desired result.

Comment: @user1934428 yes, I am aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you can actually parse in the beginning itself. But yes there is solution to your problem

1. Read the csv file
2. Change the csvData into array format
3. Apply the uniq featture of array which will remove the duplicate.

   ```
   require 'csv'
   csvData = CSV.read('./fileName.csv', :headers => true)
   csvData.to_a.uniq!
   ```

Now you can unique values without altering the initial file